# Controlling NPCs throughout the plot line of a game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out a good way to script the NPCs in my RPG.  A sample NPC interaction could go something like this:

1. NPC starts dialog #1 with player.
2. When the dialog is finished, the NPC moves to a waypoint on the map.
3. Once the NPC arrives at the waypoint and the player talks to him again, he starts dialog #2.
4. At the end of the dialog, the NPC asks a question.

   - If the player gives response A, the dialog ends.  In this case, talking to the NPC again starts dialog #2 again.
   - If the player gives response B, the NPC gives an item to the player, and disappears.  From now on, that same NPC will be present in a different Unity scene.

I've found plenty of examples of making a dialog tree, but I can't find a good way to handle complex situations like that.  One of the most challenging problems is to determine which scene -- and where in the scene -- that NPC is.  Depending on how far along the player is in the game, that NPC could be in any one of many different scenes, and will have different dialog and behavior.

Since Unity makes it easy to attach a script to my NPC's game object, I could of course do this all through a C# script.  However, that script will get pretty big and messy for important NPCs.

The path that I've gone down so far is to create an XML file.  Something like this:

```
<AgentAi>
   <ActionGroup>
      <Dialog>
         <Statement>Hi!</Statement>
         <Statement>Follow me.</Statement>   
      </Dialog>
      <MoveTo>Waypoint_1</MoveTo>
      <SetNpcState>NpcGreetedPlayer</SetNpcState>
   </ActionGroup>
   <ActionGroup>
      <Conditions>
         <State>NpcGreetedPlayer</State>
      </Conditions>
      <Dialog>
         <Statement>Here, take this.</Statement>  
      </Dialog>
      <AddItem>Dagger</AddItem>
      <MoveTo>Waypoint_2</MoveTo>
   </ActionGroup>
</AgentAi>
```

That sample would cause the NPC to greet the player and move to another spot.  Then when the player talks to him again, the NPC will give the player a dagger and move to another waypoint.

The problem with the XML is that I'm worried about it growing very large for important NPC that can be in a lot of different places depending on where the player is in the game.  I'd have to keep dynamically determining which NPCs are in a scene each time I load a new scene.  I'm not totally against doing it with XML like this, but I don't want to waste a bunch of time heading down this road if there's a better way of doing it.

Since this type of behavior is common in a lot of games, is there a good way of doing it in Unity without having to homebrew my own complex system?

Answer (score 0):

Normal software systems would use a database, once the level of complexity gets too high.

I'd setup the storyline with a numeric reference, like the pages of a book.
If they go to a higher number without interacting then the interaction is still available.

Then you can setup each interaction as a separate thing, with a start and finish number (not available before and not available after).

maybe you could do this by making the xml files separate, but I'd think you still need to tie them into the storyline.